# mysql set password authorization on server

Tags: mysql, server

Now:
 I need to input password to login mysql from a remote terminal.But in mysql server,I don't need to input password.

Then I want to input password in mysql server for login.

How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I have known.
Just to set the password of user where the user is login by localhost

```
UPDATE USER SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('password') WHERE HOST='localhost'
```